# how to use variable for add constants in Pentaho?

Tags: mysql, sql, pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

So i try to use variable to insert the value field in add constants but then it detect the variable name instead of the variable value.
[image]
This is my get variables configuration.
[image]

^ this is my add constants configuration. i dont know if its the correct way to use variable name on the value.
[image]
^ this is the variable values.

[image]
^ this is my job to and the error show that it cant execute the sql script because they detect it as the variable name instead of the value of the variable which is and sql script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add constants doesn’t allow variables as value. Use a Get variables instead.

Comment: So i change the add constants with get variable?? then how to add "sql_update" field to all row and the value of it is from the ${sql_update}??

Comment: Just like that: get variables to get var ${update_query} variable into “sql_update” field. It will be added to every row.

Comment: Btw how can i preview the data like when i run on normal transfromation? Or it just cant?

Comment: You can preview, as long as you set the variable in spoon (Edit menu/Edit environment variables)